# Why GHCi can not load the specified shard library?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have the library gsl (libgsl.dylib) installed under /usr/local/lib/ in Mac os and want to call the library function from Haskell. But I failed using GHCi but succeed using GHC.

In GHCi:

```
stack ghci --ghci-options="Bessel.hs -lgsl"
> besselJn 0 10
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _gsl_sf_bessel_J0_e
  Referenced from: libgsl.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _gsl_sf_bessel_J0_e
  Referenced from: libgsl.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

In GHC:

```
 stack ghc -- Bessel-main.hs -lgsl
 ./Bessel-main  (which is succeed)
```

Bessel.hs is a package export the function `besselJn`, `Bessel-main.hs` is just the Main module to call.

Anything wrong in the way I using GHCi ? It's weird that GHC can successfully compile/link the shared library and run, but GHCi cannot.

---

Add more info.
`Bessel.hs` is generated by `Bessel.hsc` using command `hsc2hs Bessel.hsc`(should install hsc2hs first using `stack install hsc2hs`). Following is

Bessel.hsc

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Bessel (besselJn) where

import Foreign
import Foreign.Ptr
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.C.Types
import System.IO.Unsafe

#include <gsl/gsl_sf_result.h>

data GslSfResult = GslSfResult { gsl_value :: CDouble, gsl_error :: CDouble }

instance Storable GslSfResult where
    sizeOf    _ = (#size gsl_sf_result)
    alignment _ = alignment (undefined :: CDouble)
    peek ptr = do
        value <- (#peek gsl_sf_result, val) ptr
        error <- (#peek gsl_sf_result, err) ptr
        return  GslSfResult { gsl_value = value, gsl_error = error }
    poke ptr (GslSfResult value error) = do
        (#poke gsl_sf_result, val) ptr value
        (#poke gsl_sf_result, err) ptr error


foreign import ccall unsafe "gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h gsl_sf_bessel_Jn_e"
     c_besselJn :: CInt -> CDouble -> Ptr GslSfResult -> IO CInt

foreign import ccall unsafe "gsl/gsl_errno.h gsl_set_error_handler_off"
     c_deactivate_gsl_error_handler :: IO ()

foreign import ccall unsafe "gsl/gsl_errno.h gsl_strerror"
     c_error_string :: CInt -> IO CString

besselJn :: Int -> Double -> Either String (Double, Double)
besselJn n x = unsafePerformIO $
    alloca $ \gslSfPtr -> do
        c_deactivate_gsl_error_handler
        status <- c_besselJn (fromIntegral n) (realToFrac x) gslSfPtr
        if status == 0
            then do
                GslSfResult val err <- peek gslSfPtr
                return $ Right (realToFrac val, realToFrac err)
            else do
                error <- c_error_string status
                error_message <- peekCString error
                return $ Left ("GSL error: "++error_message)
```

Bessel-main.hs

```
module Main where

import Bessel as B

main = do
  print $ B.besselJn  0 10
```